# How to avoid SQLException?

Tags: java, jdbc

This block of code gives me SQLException when i try to equal ResultSet to a String variable. can't i get a ResultSet part into a String Variable ? or any error in the code ?
And also it doesn't select any result from the database.
Pl help !

```
b1.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {

        String unm = tf1.getText().toString();
        String pwd = tf2.getPassword().toString();

        try{

            Connection con = null;
            Statement stmt = null;
            Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
            String cn = "jdbc:odbc:Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)}; DBQ=E:/userlogin.accdb";
            con = DriverManager.getConnection(cn,"","");
            stmt = con.createStatement();
            String sql = "select position from userlogin.users where users.username ='"+unm+"' and users.pwd ='"+pwd+"' ";
            ResultSet rs;
            rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql); 

            String position;

            rs.next();                
            position = rs.getString(1);

            if (position.equals("Salesman"))
             {
               frame.setVisible(false);
               Salesman.main(null);
             }

             if (rs == null)
                    {
                        JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null,
                            "Incorrect Username or Password !",
                            "Error !",
                            JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION,
                            JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE,
                            null,
                            new String[]{"Ok", "Cancel"}, // this is the array
                            "default");
                    }

                stmt.close();
            }

        catch (HeadlessException err) {
           JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null,
                            "HeadlessException !",
                            "Error !",
                            JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION,
                            JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE,
                            null,
                            new String[]{"Ok", "Cancel"}, // this is the array
                            "default");
        }   

        catch (ClassNotFoundException err) {
        JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null,
                "ClassNotFoundException !",
                "Error !",
                JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION,
                JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE,
                null,
                new String[]{"Ok", "Cancel"}, // this is the array
                "default");

        } 
         catch (SQLException err) {
            JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null,
                    "SQLException !",
                    "Error !",
                    JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION,
                    JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE,
                    null,
                    new String[]{"Ok", "Cancel"}, // this is the array
                    "default");

        } 
        }



});
```

what it says is :

Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable source code - unreported exception java.sql.SQLException; must be caught or declared to be thrown
    at javaproject.JavaProject$1.actionPerformed(JavaProject.java:65)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2018)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2341)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6505)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3321)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6270)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2229)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4861)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2287)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4832)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4492)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4422)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2273)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2719)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:713)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$000(EventQueue.java:104)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:672)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:670)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:87)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:686)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:684)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:683)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:244)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:163)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:151)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:147)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:139)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:97)
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable source code - unreported exception java.sql.SQLException; must be caught or declared to be thrown
    at javaproject.JavaProject$1.actionPerformed(JavaProject.java:65)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2018)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2341)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6505)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3321)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6270)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2229)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4861)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2287)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4832)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4492)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4422)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2273)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2719)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:713)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$000(EventQueue.java:104)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:672)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:670)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:87)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:686)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:684)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:683)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:244)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:163)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:151)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:147)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:139)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:97)
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 5 seconds)

Comment: I highly suggest [Spring JDBCTemplate](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.5.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/html/jdbc.html)

Comment: In addition to this problem, you're unlikely to want `if (position == "Salesman")` in your code.  Look into how to do String comparison in Java.

Comment: Your code does not compile, you must activate the section starting with `catch (SQLException err) {`...

Comment: just use the block in try{}catch(Exception e){}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you don't "equal" something to a variable.  You **assign** it.  (Equal is not a verb!!)

Next, you have misread the exception.  It says:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.RuntimeException: 
    Uncompilable source code - unreported exception java.sql.SQLException; 
    must be caught or declared to be thrown at ...
```

You are not "getting an SQLException".  And SQLException is not "appearing".

What you actually have is a *compilation error* ... which you have instructed your IDE to *ignore*.  Don't do that!  Fix the compilation errors before you attempt to run your application.

And the compilation error is happening because you are calling a method or methods in your code that are declared as throwing the checked exception `SQLException`, but your code neither catches the exception or declares it as being thrown by the method in which this code occurs.

In this particular case, that method is `actionPerformed` ... which is required to conform to the signature specified in the `ActionListener` interface that your anonymous class is implementing.  Therefore, you have to *catch* the exception.

---

Now I could give you some code to copy and paste into your program to fix it.  But I think it would better if you read the [Oracle Java Tutorial section on exceptions and exception handling](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/) so that you could actually *understand* what is going on here, and *understand* what you need to do to fix it.